# save one to one relationship. foreign keys in both tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

I have two tables as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE pets(
      id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          user_id int,
          any_data varchar(255),
      foreign key (user_id) references users(id),
      primary key(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE users(
      id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          pet_id int,
          any_data varchar(255),
      foreign key (pet_id) references pets(id),
      primary key(`id`)
);
```

And my models have the next:

**USERS:**

```
public function relatedPet() {
    return $this->hasOne("Pet", "pet_id");
}
```

**PETS:**

```
public function relatedUser() {
    return $this->belongsTo("User", "user_id ");
}
```

I want to save an User and relate to an existent pet, but i don't know how to do that:

```
$user= new User(array("any_data"=>"Hi, this is a test"));
$pet = Pet::find(1);
```

**How can I create the relation between the two objets?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First your users table does not need a `pet_id`. Drop it. Then

`Users` Model

```
public function pet()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Pet'); // Changed form hasMany to hasOne
}
```

`Pet` Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Now create a new `User`

```
$user = \App\User::create($data); // You need to set $fillable property
$pet = \App\Pet::findOrfail($id)
$pet->user()->associate($user);
$pet->save();
```

Examples:

```
$user = \App\User::findOrFail($id);
$pet = $user->pet

// Inserting a new user and a pet
$anotherUser = \App\User::create($data);
$anotherPet = new \App\Pet($data);
$anotherUser->pet()->save($anotherPet);

$pet = \App\Pet::findOrFail($id);
$user = $pet->user

// Inserting a new pet, a user and then associating them
$anotherPet = \App\Pet::create($data);
$anotherUser = \App\User::create($data);
$anotherPet->user()->associate($anotherUser);
$anotherPet->save()
```

Comment: I want an one to one relationship (as the title says) not one to many. And i need pet_id because i need to get the pet from user object and also the user from the pet object

Comment: Updated. Sorry about that. Changed `hasMany` to `hasOne`

Comment: I see. But i need pet_id because i need to get the pet from user object and also the user from the pet object. Im wrong?

Comment: you can get pet from user object by `$user->pet`. No need for the pet_id on users table.

Comment: And i can to get the user from a pet object?

Comment: And how can i save the pet from a user object? Please write all this details in tne answer :)

Comment: Thank you very. I will try it in few minutes and then i accept your answer :)